# Getting around broken DNS

Tags: windows, dns

I have someone who's trying to connect to the internet from a connection where the DNS server seems to be down. They can connect if I give them an ip address, but it can't resolve normal names.

I tried getting them to change the DNS used from the internet options (setting it to use Google's) - however that didn't work - apparently the isp captures all dns requests.

I also tried with a proxy but that didn't work either.

Is there another solution to the problem?

This isn't a case of censorship or anything, so there's no need to remain anonymous or whatever - I just need a way of 'forcing' the use of another dns server or routing the internet using something else.

Comment: Try using OpenDNS http://208.69.38.205/

Comment: Already tried changing the DNS from the connection options. I'll give it another go I guess.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a small list of sites where DNS lookups are failing you can add them to the host file on that machine.  Host file paths for popular operating systems:

- Linux: `/etc/hosts`
- Macintosh OS X: `/etc/hosts`
- Macintosh OS 9: In System Folder>Preferences, in the System
  Folder, see if you have a "Hosts" file. If not, create one in a text
  editor.
- WindowsXP Home: `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- Windows NT/2000/XP Pro: `c:\winnt\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- Windows 95/98/Me: `c:\windows\hosts`
- Windows 7/Vista: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: What gave you the impression that only *some* sites were failing?